# Use permission/authorization checking scheme for object other than user?

Tags: symfony

I'm a bit new to this, and I haven't found a good way to make this work.

Lets say I have a user who is an employee of 1 company. This employee may decide to put his company's stocks for sales on the stock market.

Obviously we need to check for 2 permissions:

1. Does this employee have the right to put the stocks on stock market?
2. Are this company's stocks authorized to be put on the stock market?

The first check is simple, we simply use voter or ACL to do so. The second check is what I'm trying to figure out because so far in all the documents I have read the roles/permissions are only associated with user, not with arbitrary object (the company in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="company")
 * @ORM\Entity(")
 */
class Company
{
...
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="sellable", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $sellable;
...
}
```

Then something like:

`if ($user->hasRightToSell() && $company->isSellable())`?